# Combine arrays of objects by unique key

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have two arrays of objects. One of them have visitor count per day, other have document count per day. Like this:

```
var visitors =  [ { '2014.12.25': 141 }, { '2014.12.26': 630 }, { '2014.12.30': 71 } ];
var documents = [ { '2014.12.15': 31 }, { '2014.12.26': 60, }, { '2014.12.30': 95  } ];
```

Dates may be different in each array.
How can I transform arrays to the following structure (meaning combine them by date key):

```
[ { date: '2014.12.15', visits: 0,   docs: 31 },   // here visits = 0 because there were no visitors at this date
  { date: '2014.12.25', visits: 441, docs: 0 },  // here docs = 0 because no docs were created at this date
  { date: '2014.12.26', visits: 630, docs: 60 },
  { date: '2014.12.30', visits: 71,  docs: 95 },    
]
```

Tools permitted: `JavaScript` and `Undescore.js`.

Thank you

Comment: of course, I have tried many of things, my code now have more than 2 pages to solve this, but I doubt I am going the right way. I believe there's a slick solution community may know.

Comment: Yea, this should be just a few (less than 10) lines of code...

Comment: Not trying to offend but if you're up to two pages of code to solve a problem then the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) has been completely ignored.

Comment: @Sukima if I would knew a better solution I would't have asked for help.

Comment: Whoever wrote this assignment really messed up those original objects. Why on earth would you make an array of objects with dates as keys? -.-

Comment: As far as I can see nobody here is able to solve this assignment, as you prefer to call it.

Comment: @Quest: Working on it.

Comment: Hm, make that 20 lines of code, when using proper spacing and indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a go at this in native JS.

First, let's turn those 2 arrays into more sensible objects:

```
function reduceDates(prev, curr){
    var date = Object.keys(curr)[0]; // This is why {date : value} makes no sense.
    prev[date] = curr[date];
    return prev;
}

var v = visitors.reduce(reduceDates, {});  // {2014.12.25: 141, 2014.12.26: 630, 2014.12.30: 71}
var d = documents.reduce(reduceDates, {}); // {2014.12.15: 31,  2014.12.26: 60,  2014.12.30: 95}
```

Let's combine those 2 into one object:

```
var combined = {};
for(var key in v){
    combined[key] = { date: key, visits: v[key], docs: 0 };
}
for(var key in d){
    combined[key] = combined[key] || { date: key, visits: 0 };
    combined[key].docs = d[key];
}
```

Now, `combined` is a very nice object containing your data:

```
{
  "2014.12.25": { date: "2014.12.25", visits: 141, docs: 0 },
  "2014.12.26": { date: "2014.12.26", visits: 630, docs: 60 },
  "2014.12.30": { date: "2014.12.30", visits: 71,  docs: 95 },
  "2014.12.15": { date: "2014.12.15", visits: 0,   docs: 31 }
}
```

However, since you need an array of objects, we're going to have to iterate one more time:

```
var result = [];
for(var key in combined){
    result.push(combined[key]);
}
```

Result:

```
[
  { date: "2014.12.25", visits: 141, docs: 0 },
  { date: "2014.12.26", visits: 630, docs: 60 },
  { date: "2014.12.30", visits: 71,  docs: 95 },
  { date: "2014.12.15", visits: 0,   docs: 31 }
]
```

Sure, this isn't the shortest, or best way to get the desired result, but I hope it gives you an idea of the steps involved in this process.

Comment: Downvoter: care to comment? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is loop over your data.

```
var visitors =  [ { '2014.12.25': 141 }, { '2014.12.26': 630 }, { '2014.12.30': 71 } ];
var documents = [ { '2014.12.15': 31 }, { '2014.12.26': 60, }, { '2014.12.30': 95  } ];
var data = {};
visitors.forEach(function(el){var k = Object.keys(el)[0]; data[k] = data[k] || {}; data[k].visits = el[k];});
documents.forEach(function(el){var k = Object.keys(el)[0]; data[k] = data[k] || {}; data[k].docs = el[k];});
for(prop in data){
    if(data[prop].docs === void 0){data[prop].docs = 0};
    if(data[prop].visits === void 0){data[prop].visits = 0};
}
```

This gives your data in a combined manner, all you have to do is add logic to move the date from key to a property.

Comment: @Cerbrus `void 0` is completely valid usage, I don't see what your point is.

Comment: Sure, it's valid, but it's paranoid usage of something people fairly new to JS might not be familiar with.

Comment: If someone can't loop over an array of objects I don't think it matters if they can't understand that bit.

Comment: If someone can't loop over an array of objects, that means you _really_ shouldn't use "advanced" / obscure methods like that.

Comment: I wouldn't call that advanced. But your mileage may vary.

Comment: Not necessarily, no. I suppose that depends a lot on what kind of code you work with. Regardless of both subjective opinions, how do you suppose beginners find out about different usages if they never get any contact with them?

Answer (score 0):

Another way by using underscore to combine the arrays:

```
var visitors =  [ { '2014.12.25': 141 }, { '2014.12.26': 630 }, { '2014.12.30': 71 } ];
var documents = [ { '2014.12.15': 31 }, { '2014.12.26': 60, }, { '2014.12.30': 95  } ];

var visits = new Array();
var docs = new Array();

for (i=0; i < visitors.length; i++) {
    for (key in visitors[i])    {    
        visits.push({"date": key, "visits": visitors[i][key], "docs":0});
    }
}

for (i=0; i < documents.length; i++) {
    for (key in documents[i])    {
        docs.push({"date": key,"docs": documents[i][key]});
    }
}

mergeByProperty(visits, docs, 'date');

function mergeByProperty(visits, docs, prop) {
    _.each(docs, function(arr2obj) {
        var arr1obj = _.find(visits, function(arr1obj) {
            return arr1obj[prop] === arr2obj[prop];
        });

        //If the object already exist extend it with the new values from arr2, otherwise just add the new object to arr1
        arr1obj ? _.extend(arr1obj, arr2obj) : visits.push(arr2obj);
    });
}

console.log(visits);
```